# Is this a suggested process for using GitHub with a team?

Tags: git, github

I am getting help from other developers for the first time on a repo that I am administrating, and I want to make sure I understand how the flow of work should go. The repo is setup under an Organization, and the other developers are members of a team with read access. I have owner access. Here is what I am thinking would be the flow of work:

1. He forks the repo
2. He creates a new branch
3. He makes changes, adding commits
4. He submits a pull request
5. I merge the pull request into the upstream branch

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's how we do things.  (He makes the branch on his own fork.)  But what you're missing is how people keep their own branches coordinated with the main fork's master branch.

We handle this by regularly rebasing off the main "upstream" branch's master, and using our own repository's master branch as a copy of upstream's:

On our own repository's master:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git rebase upstream/master
$ git push origin master
```

Periodically, on our branches:

```
$ git rebase master
```

We're also careful to avoid changing the same lines of the same files.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to do this through the GitHub for Windows GUI?