# Diff between local and remote repositories?

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo from an organization in github and made some changes locally and pushed them , the changes are reflected in my forked copy on my account but not the original copy on the organization account.

How can I compare these two repos locally and merge them together.

Assume I have access to the original repo.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28311094/1969198) describes how to merge an upstream branch into your local branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`remote`s](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes):

```
git remote add upstream https://path-to-original.repo
```

Note that the name `upstream` can be anything you like. After adding a `remote`, running `git fetch upstream` [helps you](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more
>   other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their
>   histories.

`fetch` is necessary if you for example don't have some branches of the `upstream`.

Now you can pull (assuming you are on the same branch) using:

```
git push upstream master
```

Now to compare your for example `master` with `master` of remote you would write something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801150/2295964):

```
git diff master upstream/master
```

You could list all of your `remote`s using:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: Error !   fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files

Comment: @ak94 sorry my bad, it should've been `git remote add`. I corrected the mistake!

Comment: @ak94 I'll add that for ref. also!